# Scripting Local Security Policy

Tags: security, deployment

On a servers Local Security Policy I need to give a user rights to "Allow logon locally".

How do I do that through a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Windows 2003 Resource Kit you need to use the ntrights.exe

```
ntrights -u userName +r SeInteractiveLogonRight
```

More details about ntrights [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276)

Comment: That link no longer exists. If it helps, I wrote an open-source replacement for `ntrights`: [https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan)