# script for Local Security Policy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm looking for some guidance on how to automat applying a set of permissions withn the local security policy to a multiple users on multiple servers.

For example, via a script, I want to apply "act as part of the operating system" and "adjust memoroy quotas for a process"  to user TEST1 and TEST2.

Any feedback on how to get started would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command line, the Microsoft-provided solution is secedit. AppDeploy is a great resource for packaging in general, and they have a good page on secedit here: http://www.osdeploy.com/tips/detail.asp?id=23

In short, change your policies using the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in, then export with secedit as in this page (http://www.webservertalk.com/message534715.html -- also assuming this  computer isn't a member of a domain), then import as usual.

Is this machine domain joined? If so, you'll need to make sure no domain policies are applied. Otherwise the domain policies will be exported along with the local ones.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler answer here:

[Scripting Local Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564979/scripting-local-security-policy/1565175#1565175)

Use ntrights.exe from the Windows 2003 Resource Kit.

However, this doesn't seem to help with the "adjust memory quotas for a process" right.