# I need a script for enabling or disabling "password must meet complexity requirements"

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, registry

Does anyone know how to make a .bat- / .vbs- / .reg script for enabling or disabling "password must meet complexity requirements" ? (windows 7)

*This is how to do it manually: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/72371-password-must-meet-complexity-requirements-enable.html*

Comment: possible duplicate of [script for Local Security Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910978/script-for-local-security-policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this page explaining in detail what i wanted to do :)

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/secedit.php